# How to append a special character in awk?

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have three files with different column and row size. For example,

```
ifile1.txt        ifile2.txt        ifile3.txt
  1    2    2       1    6            3     8
  2    5    6       3    8            9     0
  3    8    7       6    8           23     6
  6    7    6      23    6           44     5
  9   87   87      44    7           56     7
 23    6    6      56    8           78    89
 44    5   76      99    0           95    65
 56    6    7                        99    78
 78    7    8                       106     0
 95    6    7                       110     6
 99    6    4                  
106    5   34                  
110    6    4                  

Here ifile1.txt has 3 coulmns and 13 rows, 
     ifile2.txt has 2 columns and 7 rows, 
     ifile3.txt has 2 columns and 10 rows.
     1st column of each ifile is the ID, 
     This ID is sometimes missing in ifile2.txt and ifile3.txt.
```

I would like to make an outfile.txt with 4 columns whose 1st column would have all the IDs as in ifile1.txt, while the 2nd coulmn will be $3 from ifile1.txt, 3rd and 4th column will be $2 from ifile2.txt and ifile3.txt and the missing stations in ifile2.txt and ifile3.txt will be assigned as a special charecter '?'.

Desire output:

```
outfile.txt
  1     2     6     ?
  2     6     ?     ?
  3     7     8     8
  6     6     8     ?
  9    87     ?     0
 23     6     6     6
 44    76     7     5
 56     7     8     7
 78     8     ?    89
 95     7     ?    65
 99     4     0    78
106    34     ?     0
110     4     ?     6
```

I was trying with the following algorithm, but can't able to write a script.

```
for each i in $1, awk '{printf "%3s %3s %3s %3s\n", $1, $3 (from ifile1.txt), 
check if i is present in $1 (ifile2.txt), then
           write corresponding $2 values from ifile2.txt
      else write ?
similarly check for ifile3.txt
```

Comment: For us to test a potential solution we'd have to manually pull apart what;s in your question to create 3 input files. I doubt if many people will bother to do that - [edit] your question to show the 3 input files separately rather than pasted together to make it easy on us so we're more likely to help you. And make each file about 3-5 lines, there's no need for 10+ lines of sample input in each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with GNU AWK using this script:

**script.awk**

```
# read lines from the three files 
ARGIND == 1 { file1[ $1 ] = $3
              # init the other files with ?
              file2[ $1 ] = "?"
              file3[ $1 ] = "?"
              next;
            }

ARGIND == 2 { file2[ $1 ] = $2
              next;
            }

ARGIND == 3 { file3[ $1 ] = $2
              next;
            }

# output the collected information
END         { for( k in file1) { 
                printf("%3s%6s%6s%6s\n", k, file1[ k ], file2[ k ], file3[ k ])
              }
            }
```

Run the script like this: `awk -f script.awk ifile1.txt ifile2.txt ifile3.txt > outfile.txt`